# Popen(*.exe) How to simulate Enter within the newly opened application?

Tags: python, windows

Good day.  My attempts to simulate the Enter key within SQL Server Mgmt Studio when Popen calls ssms.exe have failed.  What do I need to code, please?  I am obviously a Python newbie. ***The goal is to hit Enter so that SSMS will "connect" once it is launched.  See screenshot if needed.  Much appreciated.

```
#! python3
from subprocess import Popen
import pyautogui
import time
import os
import signal

## 1. To open SSMS:
proc = Popen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\Ssms.exe", shell=True)
print("After Popen")

proc.wait()
print("After wait")

focus = False
print("After focus")

while (focus == False):
    print("In While loop")
    focus = pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    if (focus == True):
        break
```

[image: Window Pop-up for SSMS]

Comment: `Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`, then you can `proc.communicate('\n')` or such.

Comment: You're not going to be able to manipulate a GUI program directly through popen

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. I suspect that won't work

Comment: You need to look up robot libraries

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...certainly won't if it's a GUI app. That's hardly a question about `Popen`, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Hence my close vote:)

Comment: Hmm. Arguably this could be refocused on pyautogui, not on Popen (or Python-the-language/library); might be a reasonable question there.

Comment: Thanks for the input, everyone.